# How to fix <urlopen error ……. unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:997)> in Ubuntu?

Tags: linux, security, updating, ubuntu-22.04

I can't report a bug due to the above mentioned reason. I am using Ubuntu 22.04 LTS (Only Ubuntu). How can I fix this issue. May be because of this issue I can't attach my system to Canonical Livepatch.

Answer (score 0):

Though this is not a brilliant method I could fix it by removing one of the 'Other Softwares' repositories (that comes in etc/apt/sources.list.d) in 'Software and Updates' App.